# api accessible from inside of docker but not from host

Tags: docker, macos, docker-compose, dockerfile, amazon-ecr

i am running an MQ docker with the following command:

```
docker run -d \           
  -p 8161:8161 \          
  -p 61616:61616 \
  --name mq \
  -e ACTIVEMQ_ADMIN_LOGIN=admin \
  -e ACTIVEMQ_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin \
  --memory=768m \
  [ecr].dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/activemq:build-31
```

after the docker is up and running, I run the following wget command:

```
# wget localhost:8161
--2023-12-13 14:55:05--  http://localhost:8161/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1, ::1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8161... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://localhost:8161/index.html [following]
--2023-12-13 14:55:05--  http://localhost:8161/index.html
Reusing existing connection to localhost:8161.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 6048 (5.9K) [text/html]
Saving to: 'index.html'

index.html                                                       100%[========================================================================================================================================================>]   5.91K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2023-12-13 14:55:05 (460 MB/s) - 'index.html' saved [6048/6048]
```

now when running a similar curl command (I'm on mac so I don't have wget) I get this:

```
nirflatau@Nirs-MacBook-Air ~ % curl localhost:8161
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
nirflatau@Nirs-MacBook-Air ~ % curl http://localhost:8161/
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

(i though maybe the http made any difference?)

my issue is, as stated above, I cant access the API from outside the container despite using -p tag

this is the docker image im using:

```
FROM [].dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/base-java-image:build-30
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y wget \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN wget -O activemq.tar.gz https://archive.apache.org/dist/activemq/6.0.0/apache-activemq-6.0.0-bin.tar.gz
RUN tar -xzf activemq.tar.gz
COPY ActiveMQ/activemq.xml apache-activemq-6.0.0/conf/activemq.xml
CMD ["apache-activemq-6.0.0/bin/activemq", "console"]
```

(the base java image is debiam stable slim with JDK 17)

if i need to add any other info please tell me (:
thanks

Comment: What's the exact issue you're facing ? I'm not sure I quite understand.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve], for example including the application source code that shows how you're setting up the network listener?

Comment: @ABWassim my issue that the api is not accessible from outside the container despite me using the -p tag. will edit this post to make it clearer

Comment: As David said above could you share a minimal reproducible example ?

Comment: @ABWassim i udated it to include my dockerfile. it runs on a debian stable slim with JDK 17. if needed I can also get that dockerfile (for javabaseimage) .

i hope that's enough to reproduce it, if not please tell me. total stack overflow noob here, not sure if that's all that's needed

Comment: @ABWassim i ended up solving it manually, thanks for the help (:

for anyone facing this issue too, just add this to dockerfile

RUN  sed -i "s|127.0.0.1|0.0.0.0|g" $ACTIVEMQ_HOME/conf/jetty.xml